# how does ros schedule nodes

Tags: ros, linux, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how does ros schedule nodes? is this simply using the linux scheduler?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319507/how-does-ros-schedule-nodes/) by [zaddan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32031/zaddan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, ROS 1 uses the linux scheduler. By default, roscpp has a background thread to handle socket activity, and processes callbacks serially on the main thread when you can `ros::spin()` or `ros::spinOnce()`. You can change how many threads are used by using an async spinner or multithreaded spinner.

You are free to use the linux tools for scheduling to change how linux schedules your processes or threads. (I am not sure about ROS 2 but I think it is the same).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zaddan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32031/zaddan/) on 2019-03-25**:
thanks for the answer. So does ros actually use linux scheduler or it simply stays out of scheduling (and let linux take care the scheduling of nodes, since nodes are processes anyway and hence the unit of scheduling that linux deals with)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-03-25**:
ROS stays out of scheduling completely.

**Comment by [zaddan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32031/zaddan/) on 2019-03-25**:
thanks for the clarification.